# What sealant should I buy to secure cable in brick?

Tags: brick, mortar, ethernet, sealant

I have an ethernet cable that goes into house from the outside wall.

What sealant should I look for that will not crack the cable?

I need to keep wind and rain out of the house from the hole.

It has to be compatible with plastic.

Comment: mount a weatherproof enclosure on the wall outside and install an ethernet lightning arrestor in the box

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a paintable silicone but with brick would use clear , silicone is what the cable and satellite company's used on my homes and I use it at work also for sealing small holes.

Comment: I personally would err on the side of the caution and stick to a neutral cure (oxime or alkoxy) formulation...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some [**Great Stuff**](https://www.grainger.com/product/48WK15?gclid=CjwKCAiA7vTiBRAqEiwA4NTO6_y48qe93GqVzJ59-QbNYAyaiGooZCkQvKOX1_VQSdhqlUwatGAteRoCvQYQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAiA7vTiBRAqEiwA4NTO6_y48qe93GqVzJ59-QbNYAyaiGooZCkQvKOX1_VQSdhqlUwatGAteRoCvQYQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!281741802931!!!g!427397951921!).

[image]